# Some logical Error in basic registration system in C

Tags: c

I got an assignment to make a program for a registration system, here I have completed it half as it registers the user but when it comes to logging in, I am unable to get an output whereas I believe the program is correct! I am trying to compare two arrays one that we used for registration and the second for the login input.

```
int main(){
    char password[20],user_nam[7];
    int length=0,l1,length2=0,num_f=0,cap_f=0,sm_f=0,t=0,choice=0;
    int i=0,count1=0,count2=0;
    
    printf("\nPlease Enter your User-Name(5 alphabets): ");
    gets(user_nam);
    for (length2 = 0; user_nam[length2] != '\0'; ++length2);
    printf("\n %d",length2);

    if (length2==5){
        printf("\nYour password should validate following conditions;");
        printf("\n 1. 6 Characters!\n 2. Atleast 1 numeric! \n 3. Atleast 1 Capital! \n 4. Atleast 1 small letter!");
        printf("\n\nPlease Enter your passowrd: ");
        gets(password);
        for (length = 0; password[length] != '\0'; ++length);
        if (length==6){
            printf("\n%d",length);
            for (l1=0;l1<length;l1++){
                if (password[l1]>='a' && password[l1]<='z'){
                    ++sm_f;}
                if (password[l1]>='A' && password[l1]<= 'Z'){
                    ++cap_f;
                    }
                if (password[l1]>='0' && password[l1]<='9'){
                    ++num_f;
                    }
                }
            if (num_f<1){
                printf("\nPlease Add atleast 1 number to the password!");
                ++t;}
            if (cap_f<1){
                printf("\nPlease add atleast 1 capital alphabet to the password!");
                ++t;}
            if (sm_f<1){
                printf("\nPlease add atleast 1 small alphabet to the password!");
                ++t;}
            if (t==0)
                printf("\nAccount Created Successfully!");
            else
                printf("\nTry again!");
            
        }
        else{
            printf("\nPlease Enter Valid Password! Try again.");
            }
        
    }
    
    else{
        printf("\nPlease Enter valid 5 character user name!");  
        }
    printf("\nTo Login Please Enter 1 or -1 to End: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
        char l_pass[10],l_name[7];
        if (choice!=-1 && choice ==1){
            printf("\nPlease Enter your user name: ");
            scanf(" %c",&l_name);
            printf("\n");
            
            for (i=0;i<length2;i++){
                if (l_name[i] == user_nam[i]){
                    (count1 = count1 + 1);
                    printf("%d",count1);
                    }
            }
            
            if (count1==5){
                printf("\nPlease Enter your  password: ");
                gets(l_pass);
                for (i=0;i<length;i++){
                    if (l_pass[i] == password[i])
                        count2+=1;
                    }
                }
            else{
                printf("\nInvalid User Name!");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: regarding: `gets(user_nam);`  The function `gets()` has been depreciated for decades and comply removed  from the C language around 2009.  Your compiler should have told you about this.

Comment: regarding: `if (choice!=-1 && choice ==1){
            printf("\nPlease Enter your user name: ");`  SInce 1 or -1 is toend the program, why is the code continuing to execute?

Comment: `char password[20],user_nam[7];` and `gets(user_nam);`  this enables the user to enter any number of characters.  The result (when the user enters more that 6 characters is a buffer overflow ->> results in undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `for (length = 0; password[length] != '\0'; ++length);`  suggest using the function: `strlen()`

Comment: regarding: `if (count1==5){
                printf("\nPlease Enter your  password: ");
                gets(l_pass);
                for (i=0;i<length;i++){`  there is no relationship between `length` and the length of the `password`  Suggest the `for()` loop check for each character not being `'\0'

Comment: suggest using the function `fgets()` for inputting strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the line `scanf(" %c",&l_name);`.

Replace it with `scanf("%s",l_name);`

Comment: however, should have a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of `l_name`.  1 less because the `%s` input conversion specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case because he is comparing using a for loop against the entered user name.